# What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink to a Pdf bookmark?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, rtf, bookmarks

I had a Word Document that I converted into a Pdf file while retaining it's bookmarks (word bookmarks). How can I do a field code that creates a hyperlink jumping to a specific bookmark in my Pdf document ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard [RTF version 1.5](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm).

The example for bookmark with formtext would be

```
{\field{\*\fldinst {\*\bkmkstart Text1} FORMTEXT {{\*\datafield
00000000000000000554657874310008476565207768697a0000000000000000000000}}}
{\fldrslt Testing the formtext field}}{\*\bkmkend Text1}\par
```

The example for URL would be

```
This is an example at: \f1{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK 
"http://www.cnn.com/"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\f0 Go to CNN website\f0 }}}\ulnone\f0\fs24 .\par
```

Once you put them in a file, say test.rtf, you can open it with MicrosoftWord, then select "Select" tab, click "Bookmark", you will be able to see it and choose "Go To" button to jump to the location.

[image]

Comment: I think I don't understand the "FORMTEXT" thing. Which part of the field code shows the path to the PDF bookmark ?

Comment: And I think you didn't understand my question.

I write a RTF document and in this RTF document, I want to put an hyperlink to a bookmark in another PDF document. Which fieldcode do I need to write in my RTF document to get this hyperkink to jump to this bookmark ?

Comment: I see, I think the RTF HYPERLINK can only be associated with a) existing file b) web URL, c) Location in current document. The bookmark in another PDF document would probably be out of these three cases.

Comment: Another thought, if you will be using Acrobat to open PDF file, then you can use **named destination** as mentioned in this post [link to pdf named destination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125632/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-bookmark-within-a-pdf-using-url-parameters?rq=1)

Comment: I'll try and let you know ! Thanks :)